# Why does the unicode symbol \ u25B6 not appear in the color expected in TextEdit with Android 11?

Tags: android

I am using the unicode symbol \ u25B6 to display a black right pointer in a TextView. I have three tablets with different versions of Android. My 2 tablets with version 6.0.0 as well as 7.1.1 show me the black right pointer correctly, but my tablet with version 11 shows me a white right pointer inside a blue square. Can someone explain to me the reason.

Comment: Can I ask you to tell me your result of a simple setText test like the one below for Android versions other than 6.0.0, 7.1.1 and 11.

myTextView.setText ("\u25B6");

You should see a symbol as it appears on the following link:

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b6/index.htm

If you can tell me which version of android you used.

Thank you